# complex sql query many to many

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, many-to-many

I've been created my database like that:

[image: My database diagram]

I want to select person and movie names which is same person act as "Oyuncu" and "Senarist"

Please help me. I wrote a query like that;

```
select 
    MovieName,PersonName,RoleName 
from 
    Movies,
    MoviesPersonRole,
    PersonRole,
    Person,
    Role
where 
    Movies.Id = MoviesPersonRole.MovieId 
    and 
    PersonRole.Id = MoviesPersonRole.PersonRoleId 
    and 
    PersonRole.RoleId = Role.Id 
    and 
    PersonRole.PersonId = Person.Id
```

and the results are

```
MovieName         PersonName    RoleName
Pulp Fiction       Mehmet        Oyuncu
Pulp Fiction       Mehmet        Senarist
Matrix             Aylin         Oyuncu
LOTR               Gökberk       Oyuncu
LOTR               Gökberk       Senarist
Pulp Fiction       Aylin         Oyuncu
```

Comment: What is the db engine?

Comment: MSSQL Server my db engine

Comment: You mean same actor doing BOTH Oyuncu and Senarist roles?

Comment: Yeah bro. I agreed what you said. 
I want to select this situation's movie name and Person Name

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Either a self join, or group by having count(distinct role) = 2

Comment: I only want actor names which are both Oyuncu and Senarist. Only the actor has two roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try somethong like this:

```
SELECT X.MovieName, X.PersonName FROM (
  SELECT M.MovieName, PE.PersonName, COUNT(*) AS RoleCount
    FROM Movies M
    INNER JOIN MoviesPersonRole MPR ON (MPR.MovieId=M.Id)
    INNER JOIN PersonRole PR ON (PR.Id = MPR.PersonRoleId)
    INNER JOIN Person PE ON (PE.Id = PR.PersonId)
    INNER JOIN Role R ON (R.Id = PR.RoleId)
    WHERE R.RoleName='Oyuncu' OR R.RoleName='Senarist' 
    GROUP BY M.MovieName, PE.PersonName
  ) X WHERE X.RoleCount>1
```

Comment: Thanks bro. This was awasome for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line your query

```
and Role.RoleName in('Oyuncu' ,'Senarist')
```

Comment: I added this line and same results. 

I want to select only who acted same film as 'Oyuncu' and 'Senarist'

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect OP is asking for actors doing BOTH Oyuncu and Senarist roles.

Answer (score 1):

A second Join on Role should do it:

```
SELECT  MovieName ,
        PersonName ,
        RoleName
FROM    Movies
        JOIN MoviesPersonRole ON Movies.Id = MoviesPersonRole.MovieId
        JOIN PersonRole ON PersonRole.Id = MoviesPersonRole.PersonRoleId
        JOIN Person ON PersonRole.PersonId = Person.Id
        JOIN Role Role1 ON PersonRole.RoleId = Role1.Id
        JOIN Role Role2 ON PersonRole.RoleId = Role2.Id
WHERE   Role1.RoleName = 'Oyuncu'
        AND Role2.RoleName = 'Senarist'
```

Comment: Can't we do it without joins? We have too much relations between our tables

Comment: The query you wrote is also joining the tables, it just uses a different (deprecated) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query:

```
SELECT  MovieName ,
        PersonName ,
        RoleName
FROM    Movies,
        MoviesPersonRole,
        PersonRole,
        Person,
        Role
WHERE   Role1.RoleName = 'Oyuncu'
        AND Role2.RoleName = 'Senarist'
        AND Movies.Id = MoviesPersonRole.MovieId 
        AND PersonRole.Id = MoviesPersonRole.PersonRoleId 
        AND PersonRole.RoleId = Role.Id 
        AND PersonRole.PersonId = Person.Id
```